# .Net Web API - GetCookie() returns empty collection

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I tried to read a language cookie (which i set on the client) in an `ApiController` in my backend Web API like this:

```
var cookieHeaderValue = Request.Headers.GetCookies("lang").FirstOrDefault();
```

and my request header looks like this:
[image]

also the line

```
Request.Headers.GetCookies();
```

returns an empty Collection...
Can anybody tell my why and what i can do against it? 
Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parsing of the CookieHeaderValue will fail because of the '?' in your authentication cookie name. Try to remove the questionmark.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a "fully manual" and very ugly means of cookie extraction:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves an individual cookie from the cookies collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request"></param>
    /// <param name="cookieName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetCookie(HttpRequestMessage request, string cookieName)
    {
        //var vHeaders = request.Headers;
        //foreach (var vHeader in vHeaders)
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vHeader.Key + " - " + vHeader.Value);

        var vCookies = request.Headers.Where(H => H.Key.ToLower() == "cookie");
        if (vCookies != null)
        {
            var vArrCookie = vCookies.FirstOrDefault().Value;
            if (vArrCookie != null)
            {
                var vCookiePair = 
                    vArrCookie.FirstOrDefault().Split(new char[] { ';' }).Where(C => C.Trim().StartsWith(cookieName)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (vCookiePair != null)
                {
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vCookiePair);
                    var vCookie = vCookiePair.Trim().Substring(cookieName.Length + 1);
                    return vCookie;
                }
            }
        }

        // DID NOT WORK

        //CookieHeaderValue cookie = request.Headers.GetCookies(cookieName).FirstOrDefault();
        //if (cookie != null)
        //    return cookie[cookieName].Value;

        return null;
    }
```

Add this method to your base or library class visible to your Web Api controller.

Hope this will save you some time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version modified from @Roman as an extension method with a little less Linq and more accurate without the use of `StartsWith` which might cause misleading results if 2 or more cookies are prefixed with the same name

```
public static string GetCookieValue(this HttpRequestHeaders requestHeaders, string cookieName)
{
    foreach (var header in requestHeaders)
    {
        if (header.Key.Equals("Cookie", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == false)
            continue;

        var cookiesHeaderValue = header.Value.FirstOrDefault();
        if (cookiesHeaderValue == null)
            return null;

        var cookieCollection = cookiesHeaderValue.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var cookieNameValue in cookieCollection)
        {
            var parts = cookieNameValue.Split(new[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (parts.Length != 2) continue;
            if (parts[0].Trim().Equals(cookieName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return parts[1].Trim();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Some unit tests (nunit):

```
[TestCase("hello=world;cookies=are fun;", "hello", "world", true)]
[TestCase("HELlo=world;cookies=are fun", "hello", "world", true)]
[TestCase("HELlo= world;cookies=are fun", "hello", "world", true)]
[TestCase("HELlo =world;cookies=are fun", "hello", "world", true)]
[TestCase("hello = world;cookies=are fun;", "hello", "world", true)]
[TestCase("hellos=world;cookies=are fun", "hello", "world", false)]
[TestCase("hello=world;cookies?=are fun?", "hello", "world", true)]
[TestCase("hel?lo=world;cookies=are fun?", "hel?lo", "world", true)]
public void Get_Cookie_Value_From_HttpRequestHeaders(string cookieHeaderVal, string cookieName, string cookieVal, bool matches)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://test.com");
    var requestHeaders = request.Headers;
    requestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookieHeaderVal);

    var valueFromHeader = requestHeaders.GetCookieValue(cookieName);

    if (matches)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(valueFromHeader);
        Assert.AreEqual(cookieVal, valueFromHeader);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.IsNull(valueFromHeader);
    }                
}
```